# To find the minimum of $\int_0^1 (f''(x))^2dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I was trying to solve a question of an entrance exam. I am completely stuck in the problem. I am not able to find idea how to proceed. Please help me.

> Let $A$ be the set of twice continuously differentiable functions on the interval $[0, 1]$ and let $B = \{f \in A : f(0) = f(1) = 0, f'(0) = 2\}$. Find the value of $$\text{min}_{f\in B} \displaystyle \int_0^1 (f''(x))^2dx.$$

I am really sorry for not showing some effort from my side but I can not find ant way to proceed. 
Please help me. Thnx in advance.

Comment: What is $A$ in this case?

Comment: @naslundx "Let $A$ be the set of twice continuously differentiable functions on the interval [0,1]"..

Comment: What can you say about the square of a real number? What does that tell you about the value of the integral?

Comment: @Mattos Oops, I'm blind. :)

Comment: do you know calculus of variations or [Euler-Lagrange equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)?

Comment: @AlexandreHalm Yes I know that. But Can you please tell me how should I use it? I am not able to get it.

Comment: Look at the Wikipedia link, it's pretty good. Build your lagrangian ($L = y''^2$) and inject it in the E-L equation ($\partial_y L - \partial_x \partial_{y'}L + \partial^2_x \partial_{y''}L = 0$). Last step is to inject your border constraints ($y(0) = 0$ etc.)

Comment: @AlexandreHalm  Yes I got it now. Thnx a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $J = \int_0^1 L(x,f,f',f'') \ dx$ where $L(x,f,f',f'') = (f'')^2$.

Then by the Euler-Lagrange equation, $J$ has local extrema when

$$\cfrac{\partial L}{\partial f} - \cfrac{d \ }{dx}\left(\cfrac{\partial L}{\partial f'}\right) + \cfrac{d^2\ }{dx^2}\left(\cfrac{\partial L}{\partial f''}\right) = 0$$

Thus in this case, $$ 0 = \cfrac{d^2\ }{dx^2}(2f'') = 2f''''$$

and hence $f(x) = c_0 + c_1x + c_2x^2 + c_3x^3$.

Applying the conditions that define the set $B$:

$$f(0) = 0 \Rightarrow c_0 = 0. \quad\quad\quad f(1) = 0 \Rightarrow c_0 + c_1 + c_2 + c_3 = 0. \quad\quad\quad f'(0) = 2 \Rightarrow c_1 = 2$$

and we have

$$f(x) = 2x + (\alpha - 2) x^2 - \alpha x^3 \ , \quad \text{ for some value of the parameter } \alpha$$

Now evaluate $J$ and minimize it as a function of $\alpha$.

$$J(\alpha) = \int_0^1 (2\alpha - 4 - 6\alpha x)^2 \ dx = 4(\alpha^2 + 2\alpha + 4) = 4\left((\alpha+1)^2 + 3\right)$$

and $J(\alpha=-1) = 12$ is the minimum.

Therefore

$$\min_{f \in B} \int_0^1 (f'')^2 \ dx = 12$$

with the minimum attained for $f(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x$.

Comment: Thank you very much. The method is very much clear to me from your answer. Thnx again for your well written answer.

Comment: To be precise the EL equation should be interpreted in the weak sense, since the function $f$ are apriori not $C^3$. Seem that there's a regularity argument missing.